# Split LatLng coordinates into two (Python)

Tags: python

Could you please help me to split latlng coordinates into two separated values?

```
Original:
Index LatLng
0 [40.773819, -73.969132]


Trying to get something like this:
Index Lat Lng
0 40.773819 -73.969132
```

Comment: Index? Are you using a Pandas Series?

Comment: Otherwise: `lat, lon = LatLng` will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please post what you have tried so far so we can help you better. Like the above comments, I'm going to assume your working with Pandas. If you aren't, see the second comment for what to do.

Something like this seems to do the trick.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["LongLat"])
df.at[0, "LongLat"] = [40.773819, -73.969132]
df.at[1, "LongLat"] = [123.456, -654.321]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Long", "Lat"])

print(df)
print()

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    new = pd.DataFrame({"Long": row["LongLat"][0], "Lat": row["LongLat"][1]}, index=[i])
    new_df = new_df.append(new)

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```sh
                   LongLat
0  [40.773819, -73.969132]
1      [123.456, -654.321]

         Long         Lat
0   40.773819  -73.969132
1  123.456000 -654.321000
```

You can just copy and paste that code and try it out to see if it's what your looking for.